# Issue with Kafka connect filters jsonpath

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonpath

I am using kafka connect to sink the data from kafka to mongo db. During this process, I am trying to filter few of the records using Filters (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html). For this filter, we need to give a predicate specifying JSON path as condition to filter the data coming from Kafka.

Below is the json data which I am receiving from kafka

```
**Input json:**

{
    "EventMetadata": {
            "ColumnsUpdated": "FirstName,LastName,Age"
        },
    "TotalBooking__c": 1
}
```

And I have a requirement where it should satisfies below condition, if the below condition is matched kafka connect should allow such records to be inserted in mongo db.

**Condition:**
If TotalBooking__c > 0 and EventMetadata.ColumnsUpdated contains any of "FirstName" or "LastName" values it should allow such records to be inserted in mongo db.

I tried using below Kafka connect Filter operators

```
[?(@.TotalBooking__c > 0 && @.EventMetadata.ColumnsUpdated =~ /(?=\b\b)\b(FirstName|LastName)\b/)]
```

But, this will work only if the input EventMetadata.ColumnsUpdated value is having only "FirstName" or "LastName". If the value is separated by comma("FirstName,LastName,Age" as given in the above input json) then it is not working.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked Confluent documents reveal JayWay's JsonPath implementation is at work here, which is good to know since there are some more or less subtle differences in terms of features and filter syntax.

Looking at your requirements, I think you are on the right track using a regex pattern.
However, the pattern needs to match the entire string (value) since `=~` does a regex *match* not a regex *find*. In other words, we need to allow optional text at the beginning and the end using `.*` (or a more specific pattern if needed):

```
$[?(@.TotalBooking__c >0 && @.EventMetadata.ColumnsUpdated =~ /.*\b(FirstName|LastName)\b.*/)]
```